# Button in asp.net gridview not responding on webserver

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I have a ASP.NET page with a datagrid with some buttons.
When I run my project in Visual Studio Express the buttons Works perfect.

But when I copy all my files to my webserver the buttons does no longer Work.

I have a button outside the gridview and it Works okay.

Anyone have any idea why my dgridview buttons does not Work on my server?

This is my method the buttons are supposed to call:

> ```
>    protected void gvKurser_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
>    {
>        string commandValue = e.CommandName;
>        if (commandValue == "RetKursus")
>        {
>            int currentRowIndex = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
>            string ID = gvKurser.DataKeys[currentRowIndex].Value.ToString();
>            Response.Redirect("RetKursus.aspx?ID=" + ID);
>        }
>        if (commandValue == "SletKursus")
>        {
>            int currentRowIndex = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
>            string ID = gvKurser.DataKeys[currentRowIndex].Value.ToString();
>            DatabaseFunktioner.SletKursus(ID);
>            Response.Redirect("OpretKurser.aspx");
>        }
>    }
> ```

Hope this helps

Comment: You're likely getting an exception, check the `Event Viewer` on the server for a .NET exception and then post that exception here.

Comment: I cleared the event viewer on my server and tried Again. There was just one event and this was not an error or warning.

Or am I looking in the wrong place?
I click on manage on my computer and looked at event viewer

Comment: I could not find any exceptions.
Maybe I am looking in the wrong place.

Comment: What operating system is the server running? And I'm talking about the IIS server you deployed to, where it's not working.

Comment: Its a Windows Server 2003 with an IIS 6.0.

Comment: Okay, well just make sure you're looking at the `Application Log` for any errors. If you're not receiving any errors then you're going to have to clarify what in the world `does not work` means.

Comment: In my dgridview I have to buttons. One button to edit the post and a button to delete the post.

This is was is supposed to get called:

Comment: I have edit my first post with the method the buttons call.

Comment: Okay I tried my page in Firefox and it Works okay.
So I guess is a IE problem!!
Maybe some Javascript not working on IE.

Comment: In this case IE must show the JavaScript console with the error. Take a look and tell us.

Comment: This is the Javascript error I get in IE (I just turned on the show script error)
'__doPostBack' is not defined.

Comment: Hope you are not using Ajax in your application and about javascript you wrote, enable javascript on your IE and check .

Comment: I'm not using Ajax. I thinks its a IE10 error.